# Mercurial: How to jump back to previous hash? Equivalent of `cd -`

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial, is there a quick way to jump back to the previous hash without typing that hash?

For example if I am at hash `abc123` and then do `hg update def456`, is there a quick generic mercurial command to jump back to `abc123` without having to remember I was at `abc123`?

I'm looking for something analogous to bash's `cd -` which takes you to the last directory you `cd`'d out of without having to type out that directory explicitly.

If there isn't one, is it easy to write a little extension where I can type something like `hg update -` and it will do this? It would be very useful as I jump around a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial has - at least by default - no provisions to memorize the history of the checked-out revisions.

I also wouldn't count on a completely brain dead way to exist.

I'd first try to hack this feature by means of a hook to `hg update` where I check the parameter for the special case of '-' and replace it by a stored value. And if update is called without that special value, I'd try to store it in that very file I retrieve it from. But I cannot guarantee that such approach will work.